# Devise - create user account with confirmed without sending out an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I integrated devise with facebook. Now when I create a user account after the user has logged in with his/her facebook account,

```
  user = User.create(:email => data["email"], 
                     :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
  user.confirmed_at = DateTime.now
  user.save!
```

even though the account has been confirmed, an confirmation email is still fired. Any idea how I can turn the email firing off?

Comment: Take `:confirmation` out of the list of modules passed to devise on the user class?  Since you aren't actually using it.

Comment: well but other users who register on my site DO need to be email confirmed

Comment: I think @disappeardng is asking for an exception case.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The confirm callback happens after create, so it's happening on line 1 of your example, before you set `confirmed_at` manually.

As per the comments, the most correct thing to do would be to use the method provided for this purpose, [`#skip_confirmation!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L156).  Setting `confirmed_at` manually will work, but it circumvents the provided API, which is something which should be avoided when possible.

So, something like:

```
user = User.new(user_attrs)
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
```

---

Original answer:

If you pass the `confirmed_at` along with your `create` arguments, the mail should not be sent, as the test of whether or not an account is already "confirmed" is to look at whether or not that date is set.

```
User.create(
  :email => data['email'], 
  :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20], 
  :confirmed_at => DateTime.now
)
```

That, or just use `new` instead of `create` to build your user record.

Comment: fyi I had to declare confirmed_at as a attr_accessible (dunno if that's a potential security breach). Other than that this works!

Comment: Use User.new and user.skip_confirmation! to avoid having to make confirmed_at accessible.

Comment: Using new doesn't work as the email is sent when you call save! @waldo's suggestion on skip_confirmation works though

Comment: @Khash No, the point is that you need to set `confirmed_at` before saving.  Simply using `new` over `create` changes nothing, but if he'd used `new` then set `confirmed_at` before saving, the email would not have been sent. In fact, all `skip_confirmation!` does is set `confirmed_at`.

Comment: That being said, allowing the provided `skip_confirmation!` to handle the actual work is preferable.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Why do you suggest `DateTime.now` instead of `Time.now`? I checked my Devise definition for Mongoid and it uses `Time`.

Comment: @DavidJames Old habits?  `Time.now` is certainly fine in this case.  Historically `DateTime` was more appropriate for working with dates.  I don't think it even matters anymore in 1.9.2+

Comment: Devise itself currently uses `Time.now.utc`.  It was `Time.now` at the time of this bug.  Yet another reason to just use the provided `skip_confirmation!` method.  I'm going to update the answer.

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to prevent sending the email, you can use `#skip_confirmation_notification`, like so:

```
user = User.new(your, args)
user.skip_confirmation_notification!
user.save!
```

See [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FConfirmable%3Askip_confirmation_notification%21)

> Skips sending the confirmation/reconfirmation notification email
>   after_create/after_update. Unlike #skip_confirmation!, record still
>   requires confirmation.

Comment: This worked for me! Top answer didn't. :( Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Rails console

```
rails c
```

Note the user (through id) or using rails helper methods, eg. first, last.
Create a variable to hold the user.

```
user =  User.last
```

Use the skip_confirmation helper to confirm the user, then save.

```
user.skip_confirmation
user.save
```