# How to setup an admin with the seed file through devise and cancancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, devise-confirmable

I'm trying to setup an admin account so that the admin can sign in to the backend and start using it. But when I seed the file (rake db:seed) for the admin user, I get an email and when I click on it I get a message that the

`translation missing` with `account has been successfully created but that it is not activated`?

The app uses devise's confirmable module, in a rails 3 app.

I tried creating the user through the rails console, to bypass the confirmable module, with no luck. But when I try to log in, I get a message that my account hasn't been activated?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465467/devise-create-user-account-with-confirmed-without-sending-out-an-email specifically use `.skip_confirmation!`

Comment: Yes, I tried using it but I still get the message, "Your account has not been activated", when I try to log in....

Comment: you also need to do `.save` after `.skip_confirmation!` because `.skip_confirmation!` doesnt save the record yet

Comment: doesn't work, I still get the same message, that the account is still not activated...don't know whats causing it..